# Uncaught ReferenceError jquery and Django (model.Form)

Tags: python, jquery, django

I am having an Exception thrown after calling a jquery function inside the Widgets area of the forms as below :

```
class TipsterEmployeeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    
    class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/tipster-employee.js',)

    class Meta:
        model = TipsterEmployee
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'slug', 'email', 'international_prefix',
            'phone_number', 'tipster_partner',
        )
      
        widgets = {
            'tipster_partner': SelectExtra(
                attrs={'onchange': 'updateEmployeeUrl("{base_url}")'.format(
                    base_url=get_base_url())}),
        }
```

The exception thrown is :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateEmployeeUrl is not defined
```

This happens around here :

```
widgets = {
                'tipster_partner': SelectExtra(
                    attrs={'onchange': 'updateEmployeeUrl("{base_url}")'.format(
                        base_url=get_base_url())}),
            }
```

Also in the `base.html` template , the jquery link is there :

Comment: This is a javascript error. It seems the template that renders this form does not have the js file that defined what `updateEmployeeUrl` is

Comment: @bdbd, true but the file is already there